# Get vendor id for each purchaseorderdetail id adventureworks

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I want to get the corresponding `vendorID` for each row in `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail`. I'm using AdventureWorks2019.

Rows in PurchaseOrderDetail: 8,845.

Rows when joining to Vendor and ProductVendor tables: 17,790

Initial query:

```
SELECT POD.*, VenDetails.[Name] AS VendorName
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor PV ON POD.ProductID = PV.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.Vendor VenDetails ON PV.BusinessEntityID = VenDetails.BusinessEntityID;
```

This returns duplicates on some rows, for example `WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = '8'`

Next step, try to use the `PreferredVendorStatus`:

```
SELECT POD.*, VenDetails.[Name] AS VendorName, VenDetails.PreferredVendorStatus
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor PV ON POD.ProductID = PV.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.Vendor VenDetails ON PV.BusinessEntityID = VenDetails.BusinessEntityID;
WHERE VenDetails.PreferredVendorStatus = '1';
```

This returns 13,344 rows but completely misses out some rows, like `PurchaseOrderDetailID = '8'` and still returns duplicates on other rows like `PurchaseOrderDetailID = '11'`

I *think* the problem is there are vendors that supply the same product and both have the same preferred status.

I've also tried filtering the joins with

```
WHERE PV.OnOrderQty IS NOT NULL
```

and joining with the `TransactionHistory` table on `ActualCost` (which is probably mixing areas of the business, not sure). But either I get NULLs on some rows, or duplicates. Can someone help me out, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am missing the obvious - `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader` contains the `VendorID` for each order - it was just counter-intuitive to me to use the summary table in a join for the details table.

```
SELECT POD.*, PV.AverageLeadTime, PV.StandardPrice, Ven.[Name] AS VendorName, Ven.PreferredVendorStatus,
    PV.LastReceiptCost AS LastSellingPrice, PV.OnOrderQty AS CurrentlyOnOrder
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader POH ON POD.PurchaseOrderID = POH.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor PV ON POD.ProductID = PV.ProductID AND POH.VendorID = PV.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.Vendor Ven ON Ven.BusinessEntityID = PV.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: You should really learn to use table aliases, they will make your queries so much more readable